# Connect to a SVN repository through VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a way to create local copies of the programs stored in the repository so I can work on them; this is my first time using SVN.

I've got an ip address, a port number, and a password for a SVN repository. Is there some way I can access the repository through Visual Studio itself (perhaps via a downloadable plug-in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use Tortoise SVN and do everything from Windows Explorer instead of doing from Visual Studio.

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Answer (score 8):

Check out http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 6):

[Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) integrates nicely with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/), it is specifically for SVN Integration to Visual Studio.